# Side-angle-side and side-angle-angle as proved by Euclid in the Elements (Proposition 26)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have small question regarding this proposition : http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI26.html

To prove that one side is equal to another, Euclid assumes that one side is bigger than the other. Finally, when Euclid arrives at a contradiction, he dismisses the assumption about the inequality of sides and considers them equal. What I was wondering is, if we assume that a side is unequal to another one (A is bigger than B) and arrive at a contradiction, shouldn't we also try the inverse, B being bigger than A and assure ourselves that we arrive also at a contradiction to conclude that finally, A is equal to B ? 
Thank you!

Comment: If the inequality went the other way, one could just switch the two triangles (and the names of the vertices and sides also) and get back to the other case.

Comment: I'm not sure of following, are you saying that it would serve nothing because... ?

Comment: Astroman: Just saying that if the sides were such that the order of the two assumed unequal ones was the other way around, then one could switch and consider the originally first triangle as the second, and vice versa.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand what you mean. But if I wanted to REALLY waste my time and write out for the two, would I be doing anything illegal ? Thanks

Comment: Nothing "illegal" or even illogical about writing out both proofs, although they would look so similar. It's just that in cases like this where there is so much symmetry mathematicians typically only run through one of the proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you accept the contradiction you get from assuming $A$ is bigger than $B$, you truly are done. For if you were to switch and now assume that $B$ is bigger than $A$, how would the proof differ? It wouldn't. You'd take the same steps to get to the same contradiction. This means it doesn't matter which of the two is bigger, as long as one is bigger. It just so happens that we called the larger one $A$. But that is completely arbitrary as we could have just as easily called it $B$. Mathematicians will often convey this idea in a proof by using the phrase, "without loss of generality." So without loss of generality, we can take $A$ to be larger than $B$.

Comment: Yes, of course the proof would be the same. What I mean is if we truly wanted to write out every single step, and we consider the two general triangles, should I have to write two times the same proof to prove that we have a contradiction inversly? (Not that I would like doing that, I prefer one time :) )

Comment: I mean, if I had time to waste and wanted to complicate my life, would doing this be correct ?

Comment: @Astroman If the proof is the same, what would be the point? It would be like completing a paper for a class, printing out two copies and handing them in as one

Comment: Yes, I guess seen this way, it seems counter productive ! ok thank you!

Comment: @Astroman no problem, I used to think the same way. But really, there is no difference between choosing $A$ and $B$. The choice is arbitrary. Happy to help :)

Comment: The reason why I asked this is because I thought that if someone came to me and asked me to prove that the inverse might not be a contradiction, I could show him both ways to "assure" him that whatever the way, it arrives at the same conclusion. (Which like you said, would be counterproductive because it's the same thing) I'm new to this type of mathematics (proof style) so I'm still learning.

Comment: @Astroman understandable, it is a very different way of thinking. Stating the minimum amount necessary and nothing more.

Comment: I plan to study Euclid in my vacations :) Anyway, thank you again. I need to go sleep now !